# How to fix issue in appium using Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, appium

I have worked on automation tool(Appium) in android using Ubuntu PC.I have written test case and run  using TestNG in eclipse.Whenever I have run test case I have got the error i.e.

```
 Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: zipAlignApk failed. Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: -f: not found

info: Error: zipAlignApk failed. Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: -f: not found

    at /usr/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/adb.js:461:19
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I am also converting build to zipAlign and using this command
 `zipalign -f -v 4 "/home/android/Desktop/app.apk" "/home/android/Desktop/app1.apk"`

Please suggest me  how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is related to your zipAlignApk install location. You might just need to make a symlink in your /bin/sh directory. Don't think this is related to appium

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the command you are using is `-f`, not `zipalign` as you intended.  The error message shows that your toolchain (specifically on line 461 of adb.js) ran a shell script/command.  The shell (/bin/sh) started and tried to locate the executable it was told to run: `-f`.  It could not find an executable file named `-f` in its $PATH, so it failed.

Since `-f` is supposed to be the first argument you pass to `zipalign` I would suspect that however it is that you put that command in your tools is incorrect and the command itself is missing when the shell is invoked.